# Magento Observer send confirmation

Tags: php, magento

I'm stuck on my Magento observer. I want to call an webservice after the order is real placed (so when the confirmation mail is sending). What observer is hooked on the confirmation e-mail?

*sales_order_place_after* is a little bit to soon (so there could be a payment failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` was the one i needed.

Comment: Seems like a valid answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 main events occurring when customer place order in magento

One is as you maintain in question

`<sales_order_place_after>`

And another one is very important when you are using third party payment gateway in magento

in that situation when customer has pay amount successful on payment gateway's page at that

time you can get from data from

`<sales_order_payment_pay>`

event and you can access order

information like

```
  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder();
```

hope this will clear your confusion regarding to get order information after placing

successful order.